# Error al tomar datos de firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy teniendo un error a tomar los datos de una documento firebase y transformarlo en objeto.
Creo que el error esta al tratar de decodificar el dato obtenido.
Yo trato de guardar un map y obtener uno tambien.

Dejo mi Objeto ( Simplificado )

```
class Pedido
{
private Map historial;
public Pedido()
    {
    }
public void setHistorial(Map historial) {
        this.historial = (Map) historial;
    }
public Map getHistorial() {
        return (Map)  historial;
    }
}
```

Mi seteado de datos ( Tambien simplificado )

```
Pedido NuevoPedido = new Pedido();

Map<String, Object> historial = new HashMap<>();
historial.put("[12/12]","[User] - Pedido Creado.");

NuevoPedido.setHistorial(historial);

 db.collection("pedidos").add(NuevoPedido);
```

Mi forma de juntar los datos:

```
DocumentReference iddocumento = db.collection("pedidos").document(pedido_id);
        iddocumento.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                Pedido pedido = documentSnapshot.toObject(Pedido.class);
            }
        });
```

Los datos en la db quedan guardados correctamente, pero este es el error que me tira en android studio cuanto intento juntar los datos:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gchu.quierodelivery, PID: 30038
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead (found in field 'historial')
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeError(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:243)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:189)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$300(CustomClassMapper.java:54)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:770)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:741)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:542)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:253)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:100)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:183)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:161)
        at com.gchu.quierodelivery.PanelPedido$1.onSuccess(PanelPedido.java:85)
        at com.gchu.quierodelivery.PanelPedido$1.onSuccess(PanelPedido.java:82)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.tasks.zzb.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:6)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7582)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30038 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

En la clase `Pedido` en vez de:

```java
class Pedido {

private Map historial;
}
```

Escribe;

```java
class Pedido {

private Map<String, String> historial;
}
```

El problema es que no le estas indicando el tipo al `Map`.